# MySql and java {getting related tables columns}

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have created 2 tables in MySQL `[items, orderList]`, the foreign key `id` in `orderlist` references the primary key `id` in items. Now I want to take all `columns{id, name, price (in Items), and quantity (in orderList)}` from 2 tables in Java, how can I show `id` once because when I query data it shows `id` from both tables?

Comment: Show what you have tried ?

Comment: what you tried exactly? you can do that with join queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with join queries, try the below query and select the fields whatever you want from two tables

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, items.price, orderList.quantity
    FROM items INNER JOIN orderList ON items.id = orderList.id
```

Comment: Thanks sir, it works. I have another question, how can set a value for a column; my mean is how to set a total Price coulmn to gets its value from price and quanitty [price*quantity}

Comment: is total price column existing in the table? then only you can use the update query to set the value

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the data only once, you need to mention where it should come from. You can try the following:

```
SELECT I.ID, I.NAME, I.PRICE, O.QUANTITY FROM ORDERLIST O, ITEMS I WHERE I.ID = O.ID
```

Here we have given aliases to both the tables and we have mentioned that the `ID` column will be picked from the `ITEMS` table.